# How to programmatically add multiple LSTM cells

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So, here is a piece of my existing code:

```
def lstm(i,o, state):
    input_gate = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(i, w_ii) + tf.matmul(o,w_io) + b_i)
    output_gate = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(i, w_oi) + tf.matmul(o,w_oo) + b_o)
    forget_gate = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(i, w_fi) + tf.matmul(o,w_fo) + b_f)
    memory_cell = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(i, w_ci) + tf.matmul(o,w_co) + b_c)

    state = forget_gate * state + input_gate * memory_cell

    output = output_gate * tf.tanh(state)
    return output, state

output = tf.zeros([batch_size, hidden_nodes])
state = tf.zeros([batch_size, hidden_nodes])

for i in range(len_section):
    output, state = lstm(data[:,i,:],output, state)
```

I've got this running which is a nice start but i'm looking to emulate another model that is using 3 LSTM cells. I'm not quite sure I know how to code this.

Would it be this:

```
for i in range(len_section):
    output, state = lstm(data[:,i,:],output, state)
    output, state = lstm(data[:,i,:],output, state)
    output, state = lstm(data[:,i,:],output, state)
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated

Comment: Yes this would actually work because you manually unrolled the LSTM.

Comment: @RickyHan thanks for the response. Can you explain why it wouldn't work if it was rolled.

Comment: You'll have to subclass RNNCell to use static_rnn or dynamic_rnn.